# MS app insights AngularPlugin vs enableAutoRouteTracking option

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm trying to understand how to do user tracking through MS App Insights, so I'm doing some reading but I still have a doubt:

Why there is an [Angular plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-framework-extensions?tabs=angular) to track route changes and uncaught exceptions if the actual [JavaScript SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-sdk-configuration#sdk-configuration) has an option called "enableAutoRouteTracking" and another one called "disableExceptionTracking"?

Is there any difference?

Why should I use the Angular plugin if the options are out of the box?